# PowerShell regex script

Tags: regex, powershell

Have a list of usernames, they are formatted in one of two ways:

John Smith

John.Smith

I would like to get just the last name from each line in a text file.

I'm guessing I have to use a -replace or -remove command, just not sure how to format the regex.

I have this:

```
$source = "path\to\name\list.txt"

$final = "path\to\final\output.txt"

(Get-Content $source -Raw) -replace "^.\.|^."", "" | Set-Content $final
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
^[^\s.]+[\s.]+
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/RWZlnr/1).

**EXPLANATION**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^\s.]+                  any character except: whitespace (\n, \r,
                           \t, \f, and " "), '.' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\s.]+                   any character of: whitespace (\n, \r, \t,
                           \f, and " "), '.' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

Another way is also possible:

```
^.*[\s.]
```

See [another proof](https://regex101.com/r/RWZlnr/2).

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [\s.]                    any character of: whitespace (\n, \r, \t,
                           \f, and " "), '.'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use `-split` on whitespace (`\s`) or dot, take the last element of the resulting array.

```
Get-Content -Path $source | ForEach-Object {($_.Trim() -split '[\s.]')[-1]} | Set-Content -Path $final
```